# asyncio.run_until_complete block after future is set

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm learning asyncio in python3, I wrote a simple RPC server and client for study, but when i test it with asyncio.run_until_complete, it blocks after the future is already set, the code is as below, checkout the **main** part. i'm using python 3.4.2

```py
import asyncio
import struct

_req_struct = struct.Struct('<4i')
_req_size = _req_struct.size

_resp_struct = struct.Struct('<3i')
_resp_size = _resp_struct.size


class SimpleRPCClient(asyncio.Protocol):
    _transport = None

    def __init__(self):
        self._pendings = {}
        self.seq_id = 0
        self._cached = bytearray()

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        """
        First event, create ref to transport
        """
        self._transport = transport

    def send(self, data):
        """
        proxy to transport.write
        """
        self._transport.write(data)

    def data_received(self, data):
        c = self._cached
        c.extend(data)
        cursor = 0
        while len(self._cached) >= (cursor + _resp_size):
            rid, status, result = _resp_struct.unpack(
                c[cursor:cursor + _resp_size])
            if rid in self._pendings:
                f = self._pendings.pop(rid)
                f.set_result(result)
                print("future result: ", f.result())

    def calc(self, oprand, op1, op2):
        rid = self.seq_id
        self.seq_id += 1
        future = asyncio.Future()
        self._pendings[rid] = future
        self.send(_req_struct.pack(rid, oprand, op1, op2))
        return future


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 8087
    _tr, client = loop.run_until_complete(loop.create_connection(
        SimpleRPCClient,
        host,
        port))
    f = client.calc(1, 3, 5)
    loop.run_until_complete(f)
    print("final result: ", f.result())
```

the function is to calc 3+5, 
when i run the program, it correctly display the result in data_received like

> future result:  8

however the program blocks after that, never shows the final result, the future is successfully set but the function do not return, why is that?

the server side is attached below if you'd like to run it

```py
import asyncio
import struct

_req_struct = struct.Struct('<4i')
_req_size = _req_struct.size

_resp_struct = struct.Struct('<3i')
_resp_size = _resp_struct.size


class SimpleRPCServer(object):

    def build_protocol(self):
        return SimpleRPCConnection()


class SimpleRPCConnection(asyncio.Protocol):
    _transport = None

    def __init__(self):
        self._cached = bytearray()

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        """
        First event, create ref to transport
        """
        self._transport = transport

    def send(self, data):
        """
        proxy to transport.write
        """
        self._transport.write(data)

    def data_received(self, data):
        c = self._cached
        c.extend(data)
        cursor = 0
        while len(self._cached) >= (cursor + _req_size):
            seq_id, oprand, op1, op2 = _req_struct.unpack(
                c[cursor:cursor + _req_size])
            self.respond(seq_id, oprand, op1, op2)
            cursor += _req_size

        if cursor > len(self._cached):
            self._cached.clear()
        else:
            self._cached[:cursor] = b''

    def respond(self, seq_id, oprand, op1, op2):
        if oprand == 1:
            self.send(_resp_struct.pack(seq_id, 0, op1 + op2))
        elif oprand == 2:
            self.send(_resp_struct.pack(seq_id, 0, op1 - op2))
        elif oprand == 3:
            self.send(_resp_struct.pack(seq_id, 0, op1 * op2))
        elif oprand == 4:
            try:
                self.send(_resp_struct.pack(seq_id, 0, op1 / op2))
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                self.send(_resp_struct.pack(seq_id, 1, 0))
        else:
            self.send(_resp_struct.pack(seq_id, 0xff, 0))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    server = SimpleRPCServer()
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.create_server(
        server.build_protocol,
        "0.0.0.0",
        8087))
    loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: don't put *all* the code you have into the question. Create a [*minimal* but complete code example instead](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- you might answer your question while creating it and it can help others to help you to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The loop in your SimpleRPCClient.data_received() method never stop.